# JavaFX ListView File Save

Tags: java, listview, javafx, cell, listitem

I'm going to try to keep my post as short as possible;

Here's my `custom Object`

```
public class ListItem {
ListItem(String text){
    this.text = text;
}

final String text;
final ObjectProperty<Font> font = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
final ObjectProperty<Color> color = new SimpleObjectProperty(Color.BLACK);
}
```

It's a cell object for holding: `String, Color, Font/int` (I just need the Fontsize, might change it to int if needed)

Using it, I created a `ListView<ListItem>`.

Now I can fill that `ListView<ListItem>` with a cell which is a `ListItem` using a `CellFactory`. That looks like [this](https://hastebin.com/delejawile.cs).

**Until here - everything works.** (The above code & explanation is for better understanding what I'm trying to do)

but now, I don't know how to do the following:

- **Saving** the `ListView`-Content to a `file`. Or a little more clearly; How can I take the whole content of my ListView, filled with custom Objects while saving all of their properties (String, Color, Int)?

A little example of how I'd imagine that to give you a better idea:

```
"entry_1":
  text: "entry text goes here"
  color: "web color code goes here (e.g. #ff4d4d)"
  fontsize: "16"
"entry_2":
  ...
```

### Update

I set up a loop, I guess it should work fine but this gives me errors;

My file/it's path:

```
private final String saveLoc = System.getenv("ProgramFiles") 
+ File.separator 
+ "simpleNotizen" 
+ File.separator 
+ "simpleNotizen.properties";
private final File save = new File(saveLoc);
```

How I call it:

```
if(!save.exists()){
    save.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    save.createNewFile();
}
```

The error (thrown on `save.createNewFile();`):

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: The System can't find the given Path`

(Or something similair, had to translate it)

I really don't get why the error is thrown, I tried FileWriter, OutputStream, File, but everytime the same error..

I also tried to give a sysout, which seems perfectly fine:

`C:\Program Files\simpleNotizen\simpleNotizen.properties`

#### Solved

If anyone wonders how I fixed it, here it is

For **saving** my `ListView` Content, I wrote a loop which repeats itself by the amount of entries there are in the ListView;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
       prop.setProperty("entry_" + Integer.toString(i),
               listView.getItems().get(i).text
               + "|"
               + listView.getItems().get(i).color.getValue()
               + "|"
               + listView.getItems().get(i).font.getValue().getSize()
               );
   }
```

My second problem appeared to be a Permission problem with the `C:\Program Files\`-Path, fixed it by replacing it w/ `APPDATA`

Comment: bad practices tend to spread ;) just saying ..

Comment: I saw your comment underneath @Fabian's answer in my last answer already

Comment: Is there any better way to do this custom Font+Colored cells ListView?

Comment: this question is too broad plus seems to be more like a XY-problem than the real thing: it's unclear what you are really after (you never "save the whole ListView to a file" instead you save the data contained in the list plus meta-data if needed). If you need debugging help a [mcve] is a must.

Comment: k den, I'll try to edit my post to make it more clear.. registered myself that it's a little messy

Comment: obviously it had no effect <g> yeah, sure: you set styles based on the content

Comment: please read the referenced help page and then _do_ what it suggests - snippets are not helpful!

Comment: loop over the list's items and write each to a file, converting each property to a string that can be parsed again on reading - it's up to you to define an appropriate format

Comment: Can you save `int`s and  `String`s to a file ? As commented by kleopatra save the **data**, and reconstruct the object when reading from file. Color can also be reresented as `String` or `int`.

Comment: see my updated post ^

Comment: Again, please provide a [mcve]. The reason we ask for this is so we can see _all_ the logic and, if needed, copy and run the code on our own machines. Note that a MCVE is not necessarily a code dump of your current code but rather an example _specifically created for Stack Overflow_.